# MATLAB: Compensating for overexposure/oversaturation in image processing

Tags: image, matlab, rgb

First post. I've been working on this issue for quite some time.

I'm working on a program that takes a picture of a spot of elliptical red laser light that has been diffused into an elliptical shape.

To do the initial theoretical tests for this application, I took the pictures with a DSLR camera, and processed the image in Matlab. However, often times the pictures were heavily overexposed/oversaturated. (Meaning the red in the center of the spot of light turned out yellow/white in the resulting image. Also the spotsize appeared bigger than reality due to overexposure) Looking at the RGB intensity graphs, the oversaturation is clear.

I could modify all the camera settings on the DSLR to get correctly exposed pictures (which were taken in a dark room). However, this app will eventually go onto an android phone, and I'll be using the phone's camera. I've done my research and many android phones don't offer much flexibility with camera manipulation. So, instead of risking that my app might not work for many phones, I decided to try developing a post-processing algorithm that compensates for oversaturation, but it's fickle and doesn't work for all cases and all light spots.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem, and if so, do you have any suggestions on how I can fix this oversaturation problem? It's extremely important that my image is not overexposed.

I'm running the tests in MATLAB at the moment. If you need more information, I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Lot of the adjustment you've mentioned should be done in a different color space:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/converting-color-data-between-color-spaces.html

Let me know if this gives you enough information to answer this question yourself

Comment: I'm not sure which color space is suitable for fixing my saturation issue. I already tried converting RGB to its luminance value, but those results weren't very promising.

Comment: Then you should've posted this code. Adjusting color/exposure etc. is an easy operation (either additive (+) or multiply by a facor (*1.x)), you just have to use the right color space. Make sure you clamp (255 etc.) then transform back

Comment: Have you tried using Matlab's rgb2hsv() function, and working on the saturation component?

Comment: I have. Using the saturation component gives me relatively decent results but only when the image is saturated. It flops when the image isn't saturated. 

I actually have a question about HSV. At the pixels that are heavily saturated, the S component goes to 0 and at the pixels that aren't saturated, the S component goes to 1. Shouldn't it be the other way around intuitively? What does S actually signify? Right now, I'm taking its complement and scaling my R values with S.

Answer (score 0):

When pixels are saturated, no processing can restore the lost information. It is lost forever. Forget about image processing to retrieve it.

You must take action before the pixel values are digitized, i.e. by acting on

- incoming amount of light (use a filter),
- iris opening,
- exposure time,
- analog gain before the A/D converter.